# How to bind C# list to an ORACLE stored procedure list parameter

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to send a list of strings as parameter to a list containing string expressions in an Oracle stored procedure with ADO.NET using C#.

My model class:

```
public class PieceList
{
    public List<string> p_PieceIdList { get; set; };
}
```

İ am sending list parameter from here to C#:

```
var p_PieceIdList = ["123456AA"];
var p_producttype = null;
.....

var veri = {
    p_PieceIdList: p_PieceIdList,
    p_producttype: p_producttype,
    .......

};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test/TestList",
    data: veri,
    success: function (data) {
```

Server-side:

```
public JsonResult TestList(PieceList pieceList)
{
    // ...
    command.Parameters.Add("p_PieceIdList", OracleDbType.Array).Value = new string[] { "23480465GA" };
    command.Parameters.Add("p_producttype", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = pieceList.p_producttype;
    command.Parameters.Add("p_outcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

These are the parameters of the Oracle stored procedure:

```
p_PieceIdList    IN T_STRING_LIST,
p_producttype    IN VARCHAR2,
-- ............
p_outcursor      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
```

I am getting this error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PIECE_LIST'
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

In summary, I am trying to send a string list as a parameter to the C# environment with AJAX. Afterwards, I want to send this list string parameter to a stored procedure in my Oracle database, but that did not work.

Comment: In future, don't create a duplicate question. Edit the question you already posted. Now we've got to get the first one deleted.

Comment: The C# driver does not support passing non-associative collections (i.e. arrays) from C# to Oracle (for whatever reason, as other drivers in other languages do support it). You need to pass an associative array (a `PLSQLAssociativeArray` type) and then if you need a non-associative array in Oracle use a function to copy the values from the associative array to the non-associative array.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `temporary tables` in Oracle- simply insert the list to the temporary table and use that table inside your SP/FUNC.

You could also serialize your list to the XML format, and define a parameter of XMLTYPE in your SP/FUNC.

Comment: Actually i  have created temporary tables but still  whats a pity  i am getting same error message.

Comment: @OsmanTÜRK remove an invalid parameter that is a reason for the error that you are having `command.Parameters.Add("p_PieceIdList", OracleDbType.Array).Value = new string[] { "23480465GA" };`

Comment: Unfortunately We can't change SP parameter . It  has created from owner project and can't change Oracle side.  And also i have changed this but Nothing happened. command.Parameters.Add("p_PieceIdList", OracleDbType.Array).Value = new string[] { "23480465GA" };